# Python module for PPPoE

Tags: windows, open-source, python, networking

I am trying to connect a new PPoE session, send and receive some data and close the session.

I there a FOSS Python module to help me?

Note that I have found https://github.com/jamiesun/pyras but it does not seem to have any documentation :-(

---

[Update] I also found [win32ras](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32ras.html) (at least, I found the documentation; I  didn't yet find a download link), which seems useful, although not greatly documented. There are a few examples around.

What I am looking for here is an authoritative answer, from someone who has experience.

I require that the recommended Python module can perform full PPPoE, including LCP configuration and PADI/PDO, etc authentication (I strongly suspect that this is handled by Windows RAS service, but require confirmation).

The recommended documentation should also have adequate documentation or code examples to show how a URL can be sent and data received over the PPPoE connection which it establishes.

Linux support is a bonus, but not a "must have".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the OP, just in case it helps anyone in future

I simulated opening Control panel/Network connections and creating a new PPPoeE connection, then simulated clicking on the icon.

```
rasPhoneBookPath="C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Network\\Connections\\Pbk\\TemporaryRasphPhonebook.pbk"
```

Search for the appropriate path (Windows moves it around in different versions, but it is always a `.pbk` file).

Write some Python code to create a similar file. here are the parts which I changed

```
with open(rasPhoneBookPath, "wt") as phoneBookFile :
    phoneBookFile.write('[' + pppoeSessionName + '\n')
    phoneBookFile.write("PhoneNumber=ACGC:AT+CGDCONT=' + bearerId + ',"IP","' + pppoeSessionName + '"\n")
```

and simulate a click to the icon by

```
rasDialResult = os.system("rasdial " + "' + pppoeSessionName + '" + " /PHONEBOOK:" + rasPhoneBookPath)
```

This works for me, on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

not good at English.
you can import module win32ras

just like this :
import win32ras

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
By the way,the module pyras is just a test,the author said:
"本着学习的目的试了试，用python实现了一个pppoe拨号客户端，实现了基本的拨号和代理检测功能（采用了 shell xu的建议），放了一个简单的开源版，界面用的Tkinter，才200多行代码。

目前在win7 64下测试OK，xp还没有测试，问题应该不大。

https://github.com/jamiesun/pyras

并没有实现PPPOE协议部分，因为我发现其实用pywin32可以很好的利用系统的pppoe功能。每个宽带连接都有一个rasphone.pbk配置文件，只要拷贝一份配置就不用调系统对话框流程来创建了，很多参数可以自己配置。使用w32ras基本可以很好的控制。

另外就是用了pycap和dpkt来抓包分析检测代理，发现目的ip为本机的http请求就判断为代理（不影响本机访问自己的http服务）

防止路由的功能我也想好了，和AAA服务器扩展下，每天都使用一个动态的用户名，用路由肯定烦死了。

使用pyinstaller打包exe，一般人反编译也不太容易。"

---

[Update by OP] I ran that through Google translate and got

> The purpose of learning to try the experiment, using python to achieve
>   a pppoe dial-up client to achieve the basic dial-up and proxy
>   detection (using the shell xu recommendations), put a simple
>   open-source version of the interface with Tkinter , Only more than 200
>   lines of code.
>
> Currently in the win7 64 test OK, xp has not been tested, the problem
>   should not be.
>
> And did not achieve PPPOE agreement, because I found that in fact can
>   be a good use pywin32 system pppoe function. Each broadband connection
>   has a rasphone.pbk configuration file, as long as a copy of the
>   configuration will not be transferred to the system dialog box to
>   create the process, many parameters can be configured. Use w32ras
>   basic can be very good control.
>
> The other is to use pycap and dpkt packet analysis and detection
>   package agent found ip for the purpose of the machine's http request
>   to determine the agent (does not affect the machine to access their
>   http service)
>
> I also want to prevent the routing function well, and AAA server
>   expansion, the daily use of a dynamic user name, with the routing
>   certainly tired of the.
>
> Use pyinstaller package exe, most people decompile is not easy.